# Optimize route on indoor map (warehouse) with R

Tags: r

Our project is focused on optimizing routes within a warehouse in R.
We have multiple locations "from" and "to" all numbered. There are also some constraints, like you have to follow specific pathways only.

[image: Sample warehouse plan] (blue - starting location, red - points to go, grey - walls (constraints, cant go through))

What is the optimal way to start off?

Comment: Can you please post some code of what you have tried so far? Please refer to [mcve] as a model

Comment: Updated the question, still did not start the R code

Answer (score 0):

Without exactly understanding what you mean by "S-shape pathways", I think you could model your problem as a network flow problem, also known as min-cut/max-flow problem. This would be a linear model, you could use the `lpSolveAPI` package for that.